# Search a very large directory for a file containing text in it's name

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, io, multiprocessing

I have a network share that contains around 300,000 files on it and it's constantly changing (files added and removed). I want to search the directory for specific text to find certain files within this directory. I have trimmed my method down about as far as I can, but it still takes over 6 minutes to complete. I can probably do it manually around the same time, depending on the number of strings I'm searching for. I want to multithread or multiprocess it, but I'm uncertain how this can be done on a single call: i.e.,

> `for filename in os.scandir(sourcedir)`.
>
> Can anyone please help me figure this out?

```
def scan(sourcedir:str, oset:set[str]|str) -> set[str]:
    found = set()
        for filename in os.scandir(sourcedir):
            for ordr in oset:
                if ordr in filename.name:
                    print(filename.name)
                    found.add(filename.name)
                    break
```

> RESULTS FROM A TYPICAL CALL:
> 516 function calls in 395.033 seconds
>
> Ordered by: standard name
>
> ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
> 6    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.000 :39(isdir)
> 6    0.000    0.000    1.346    0.224 :94(samefile)
> 12    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 :103(join)
> 30    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :150(splitdrive)
> 6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :206(split)
> 6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :240(basename)
> 6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :35(_get_bothseps)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :545(normpath)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :577(abspath)
> 1    0.000    0.000  395.033  395.033 :1()
> 1    0.000    0.000  395.033  395.033 CopyOrders.py:31(main)
> 1  389.826  389.826  389.976  389.976 CopyOrders.py:67(scan)
> 1    0.000    0.000    5.056    5.056 CopyOrders.py:88(copy)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 getopt.py:56(getopt)
> 6    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 shutil.py:170(_copyfileobj_readinto)
> 6    0.000    0.000    1.346    0.224 shutil.py:202(_samefile)
> 18    0.000    0.000    1.493    0.083 shutil.py:220(_stat)
> 6    0.001    0.000    4.295    0.716 shutil.py:226(copyfile)
> 6    0.000    0.000    0.756    0.126 shutil.py:290(copymode)
> 6    0.000    0.000    5.054    0.842 shutil.py:405(copy)
> 6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _stat.S_IMODE}
> 6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _stat.S_ISDIR}
> 6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _stat.S_ISFIFO}
> 1    0.000    0.000  395.033  395.033 {built-in method builtins.exec}
> 6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.hasattr}
> 73    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
> 38    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
> 6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.min}
> 14    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
> 12    2.180    0.182    2.180    0.182 {built-in method io.open}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method nt._getfullpathname}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method nt._path_normpath}
> 6    0.012    0.002    0.012    0.002 {built-in method nt.chmod}
> 49    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method nt.fspath}
> 1    0.149    0.149    0.149    0.149 {built-in method nt.scandir}
> 36    2.841    0.079    2.841    0.079 {built-in method nt.stat}
> 12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method sys.audit}
> 12    0.019    0.002    0.019    0.002 {method '**exit**' of '_io._IOBase' objects}
> 6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method '**exit**' of 'memoryview' objects}
> 6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
> 36    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'find' of 'str' objects}
> 12    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'readinto' of '_io.BufferedReader' objects}
> 30    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'replace' of 'str' objects}
> 6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'rstrip' of 'str' objects}
> 6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'write' of '_io.BufferedWriter' objects}

Answer (score 3):

Since you're only interested in the file names and not any of the other file attributes, you should not use `os.scandir` to incur the overhead of building objects with all the file attributes. Use `os.listdir` instead to retrieve just a list of file names.

Secondly, you can use a regex of an alternation pattern instead to more efficiently search for multiple substrings since the `re` module is written in the much faster C language.

```
import re

def scan(sourcedir:str, oset:set[str]) -> set[str]:
    regex = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, oset)))
    return set(filter(regex.search, os.listdir(sourcedir)))
```

Note that you have the `oset` parameter typed as `set[str]|str`, which makes little sense since a container of strings and a string can't be handled in a consistent manner. I've made it to be typed as `set[str]` instead in my example.

Comment: I'll give it a shot again, but in my testing listdir was a bit slower than scandir. I added "|str" to stop showing a stupid pylint error stating that set[str] was incompatible with set[str]|str. Which clearly makes no sense, but... pylint. Am I right?
I haven't tried re before, and I'm open to it, but most of the time spent is on getting the listing of files from the network share, so that's what I've been focused on.

Answer (score 0):

#### You could try [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

I don't have a directory with 300,000 files to test it on, but I'm assuming it would be pretty quick, (a few seconds).

```py
import glob

sourcedir = r'path\to\your\files'
oset = ['some','list','not','shown','in','your','code']

found = []
for ordr in oset:
# Get a list of all files in the "sourcedir" directory with "ordr" in the filename
    files = [f for f in glob.glob(f"{sourcedir}\*{ordr}*")]
    found.extend(files)

print('\n'.join(found))
```

Comment: From sources that I've seen comparing the time it takes to run a call, glob was slower than the others. I suppose it's worth testing though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding that no matter how many files I scan for, it doesn't take more than a shorter list of files (by much). So I think that the long period of time that it was taking to gather the list of existing files to compare against is akin to indexing the directory. I am using the tool for larger sets of files. For the onsies and twosies, I search manually. I suppose it is what it is.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).